# Trouble with Python. Translate Toolkit on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, translation, gettext, translate-toolkit

I need to use **po2csv** utility from [**Translate Toolkit**](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/) on Windows.

I make next step:

1. Download and install Python 2.7 in `C:\Python27\`folder
2. Adding `Path=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;OTHET_FOLDERS...` and `PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk` in system enviroment variable.
3. Reboot PC.
4. Download "Translate Toolkit 1.11.0"
5. Run command `MY_DOWNLOADS\translate-1.11.0\translate-1.11.0\python setup.py install`

After that I trying use po2csv:

```
python po2csv
python: can't open file 'po2csv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
C:\Python27\Scripts>python po2csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "po2csv", line 22, in <module>
from translate.convert import po2csv
ImportError: cannot import name po2csv
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\translate\convert>python po2csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "po2csv.py", line 27, in <module>
from translate.storage import po
ImportError: cannot import name po
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3781890, I think you should just double click the `setup.exe` rathar than doing `python setup.exe install`. Or run `python setup.py install` on `setup.py` files

Comment: @ashoka-lella Thanks, I fix this inaccuracy in question.